# Mod_rewrite Stucture page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am creating url friendliness on my website. It works it is getting the content data based on a unique url from a column of the posts table.

The problem is the page template is always the same. For example in one of the links the template structure is different, but is always getting the same template structure.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ product.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your matching rule for the page.php redirect is exactly the same as the matching rule for product.php. This means your second rule is not logically reachable because if a URL were a match for the second rule, it would already have been rewritten by the first.